# Преобразования во время компиляции

Tags: компиляция, rust

```
fn main() {

    let var = "hello".to_string(); <- Преобразование &str в String

    let var = "hello".as_bytes(); <- Преобразование &str в [u8]

}
```

Выполнятся ли эти преобразования на этапе компиляции или только при запуске программы?

Comment: В вашем случае - это метод - конвертация во время выполнения https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_bytes

Comment: Поправил ссылку

Comment: @Виктор а теперь ссылка ведёт не на тот as_bytes https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes

Comment: С чего Вы взяли, что не на тот?

Comment: @Виктор с того, что в показанном здесь коде тип String не используется (кроме результата вызова to_string)

Comment: метода одинаковые - для понимания

Comment: @Виктор это абсолютно разные методы с разными сигнатурами и разным телом

Comment: @Виктор ну и да, "метод" совсем не обязательно означает "конвертацию во время выполнения". Правильный to_bytes объявлен как `inline` и `const fn` - а значит у компилятора есть теоретическая возможность посчитать результат во время компиляции (но делает ли он так в реальности - не знаю, не проверял)

Comment: А вычисляется ли HashSet на этапе компиляции, при условии, что в нем лежат статические данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще говоря, такие вопросы не вполне корректны. Программы, написанные на языке rust, считаются выполняющимися на абстрактной rust-машине, и в рамках этой машины нет никакого разделения на "время компиляции" и "время выполнения".

Задачей же компилятора является написать такую программу в машинных кодах целевой платформы, которая будет вести себя неотличимо от заданной на вход программы, выполняющейся в той самой rust-машине. Что при этом он будет делать во время компиляции, а что оставит на время выполнения - дело компилятора.

---

Тем не менее, ваш вопрос вполне понятен. Как правило, программы пишутся с расчётом не на абстрактный интерпретатор в вакууме, а на конкретный компилятор, который умеет производить весьма конкретные оптимизации.

Так вот, для выяснения подобных вопросов существует сервис Compiler Explorer, и вот что он показывает для вашего примера (https://rust.godbolt.org/z/9x4T8YMh8):

Вызов `.as_bytes()` не требует никакой хитрой работы, и компилятор избавился от него полностью.

Вызов `.to_string()` требует выделения памяти в куче, и с этим выделением компилятор ничего не смог поделать: оно осталось в рантайме. Однако, компилятор устранил сам вызов `.to_string()`, раскрыв его